# Microbiology- Pseudomonas aeruginosa, BSAC data

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I tested *Pseudomonas aeruginosa*against various antibiotics, using Stokes and Kirby-Bauer. When I compared my results with BSAC data it was completely different (understandable) but why for a lot of the antibiotics did BSAC state 'no information available'?